# `bazel help` in machine readable format

Tags: documentation, bazel

Is there a way to invoke `bazel help` such that it outputs a machine readable format. I would like to parse all the flags that are available in Bazel and make them automatically available in [`ibazel`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel-watcher) so that I don't have to manually sync them every time a new bazel release comes out with different flags.

There used to be a `--helpxml` argument that printed things out as XML, but it seems the command line argument parser has changed and you can no longer use that. I presume there is still some way to get this, since the docs are being generated with up to date [command line](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/command-line-reference.html) info. Unfortunately the "edit this page" button on the docs site 404s and I can't figure out its origin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The docs for the flags are generated via [this genrule](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/BUILD#L543), which essentially runs `bazel help everything-as-html`, the source of which is [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/java/com/google/devtools/build/lib/runtime/commands/HelpCommand.java#L137).

There are a few other options listed in that case statement, one of which being `flags-as-proto` which emits the flags as a base64 encoded version of the [`BazelFlagsProto`](https://github.com/bazelbuild/bazel/blob/master/src/main/protobuf/bazel_flags.proto).

Potentially ibazel could read this in, load in the proto and pull out the data from there.

Comment: thanks for the wonderful answer! I'm delighted to find out how easy this was. Much easier than writing an EBNF to parse the output of `bazel help` in ANTLR. At least I learned a lot about ANTLR ;-)